# angularjs form post http interceptor not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am new to angularjs so pardon my ignorance. Here is the interceptor i have for my angularjs app

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  })

  .factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
      // Add authorization token to headers
      request: function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
        }
        return config;
      },

      // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if(response.status === 401) {
          $location.path('/login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookieStore.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
    };
  })
```

I have an html which posts the data to the server

```
<form role="form" id="addTeacherForm" data-validate="parsley" action="/api/v1/teacher" method="post">
                        <h4>Add your Teacher's data</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <input type="text" ng-model="teacher.name" name="name" class="form-control input-md"
                       placeholder="Name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <input type="date" ng-model="teacher.dob" name="dob" class="form-control input-md"
                       placeholder="Date Of Birth" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <div class="input-icon"><i class="icon-user"></i>
                Teacher's Photo
                <input type="file" id="teacherPhoto" name="teacherPhoto" accept="image/*" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" ng-model="teacher.phoneNumber"
                       class="form-control input-md" name="phoneNumber"
                       placeholder="Phone Number(Optional)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-actions text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now when i press submit on this form the request goes to the server but the interceptor doesn't get invoked and the request fails because the headers are not populated with the authorization token. Any idea why this is not being intercepted?

Comment: Interceptor get invoked only when you use $http service.

Comment: how can i make sure that the form submission goes through $http service?

Comment: You need to invoke directly `$http.post(...` normally in your controller code.

Comment: the reason i was doing it this way was because i have an image in the form too, I just edited the html to show that. How can i post the form with an image along with other inputs?

Comment: In regards to posting an image with $http service, this article might help you. https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: Have a look at this https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/